# Does Stack Exchange Markdown support MermaidJS?

Tags: discussion, markdown

**[MermaidJS](https://mermaidjs.github.io/)** was my favourite cool thing in 2018!

But I can't find a way to draw MermaidJS `graph` or `sequenceDiagram` on Stack Overflow.

I've seen many Markdown tools such as [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/app#), [Typora](https://typora.io/), [Markdown Plus](https://mdp.tylingsoft.com/) and [Markdown Monster](https://markdownmonster.west-wind.com/) support MermaidJS, and I feel a little bit restricted not having the luxury of this cool technology on Stack Exchange sites.

Adding `<!-- language: mermaid-js -->` or triple back-ticks (```` ```mermaid ````) didn't work so I assumed it is not supported.

I think this would be very useful in asking design-related questions, or in explaining complex scenarios.

So will it ever be supported? if not, what are the alternatives?

Comment: When you're making a feature request, you need to have more than vague "I think" statements. Why would it be useful exactly? Where? Do you have examples of questions or answers that could make use of it, and across SE sites? I also don't think SE supports even the full basic markdown.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It doesn't but if a site has Stack Snippets enabled you can use that functionality to include your diagram.

The mermaid documentation gives [an example of using Mermaid](https://web.archive.org/web/20191102094816/https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/usage?id=simple-usage-on-a-web-page) in a way that's compatible with Snippets.

The JavaScript snippet section to call the mermaidAPI in a separate `script` tag may not be needed.

The html snippet section must include:

- mermaid address using a `script` tag in the `src` section
- mermaid code/ graph definition declared inside a `<pre>` with `class=mermaid`

```js
mermaid.initialize({ startOnLoad: true });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/font-awesome@4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mermaid/dist/mermaid.min.js"></script>

<pre class="mermaid">
  graph LR
    A --- B
    B -->|invalid| C[fa:fa-ban forbidden]
    B -->|valid| D(fa:fa-spinner fa:fa-spin);
</pre>
```

The only downside is that visitors of your post have to click the Run code snippet button to actually see your diagram.

Comment: @flywire they reshuffled content, I updated the link.

Comment: Your version of mermaid did not support `flowchart` so pasted the bottom block into html using non-version specific `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mermaid/dist/mermaid.min.js"></script>` and did not need the top block in javascript. For the purpose of the question It was easier not to indent the mermaid code. Can I edit this into your answer?

Comment: @flywire sure, go ahead

Answer (score 15):

To indirectly post your mermaid diagram, you can edit online with https://mermaid.live/.

You can then share your chart with a link that you can use in markdown (click on the picture to see the code and edit)

```
[![Node A connects to Node B, which splits into a "forbidden" node and a node with a spinner](https://mermaid.ink/img/eyJjb2RlIjoiICAgIGdyYXBoIExSXG4gICAgICBBIC0tLSBCXG4gICAgICBCLS0-Q1tmYTpmYS1iYW4gZm9yYmlkZGVuXVxuICAgICAgQi0tPkQoZmE6ZmEtc3Bpbm5lcilcbiAgICAgICIsIm1lcm1haWQiOnsidGhlbWUiOiJkZWZhdWx0In0sInVwZGF0ZUVkaXRvciI6ZmFsc2UsImF1dG9TeW5jIjp0cnVlLCJ1cGRhdGVEaWFncmFtIjpmYWxzZX0)](https://mermaid.live/edit#eyJjb2RlIjoiICAgIGdyYXBoIExSXG4gICAgICBBIC0tLSBCXG4gICAgICBCLS0-Q1tmYTpmYS1iYW4gZm9yYmlkZGVuXVxuICAgICAgQi0tPkQoZmE6ZmEtc3Bpbm5lcilcbiAgICAgICIsIm1lcm1haWQiOiJ7XG4gIFwidGhlbWVcIjogXCJkZWZhdWx0XCJcbn0iLCJ1cGRhdGVFZGl0b3IiOmZhbHNlLCJhdXRvU3luYyI6dHJ1ZSwidXBkYXRlRGlhZ3JhbSI6ZmFsc2V9)
```

[image: Node A connects to Node B, which splits into a "forbidden" node and a node with a spinner]

Comment: The other answer from rene uses the built-in snippet and does not require third-parties. But this method has a live preview and doesn't require an extra click, so I'm marking this as the answer.

Comment: To generate the markdown link go to the Actions link in the left-hand pane of the Mermaid Live Editor and hit the 'Copy Markdown' button.

Answer (score 9):

As far as I know, no. It might be shiny but amusingly the preferred way to do graphs and diagrams on SE is using ASCII and code blocks.

```
  +--------------------+
  |                    |
  |                    |
  |   Computer         |
  |                    |    <--------------------------+
  |                    |          IF Man TOUCHES Computer
  |                    |          THEN Dog bites Man   |
  +--------+-----------+          ELSE SLEEP           |
           ^                                           |
           |                                           |
           X   No touchie!                             |
           |                                           |
           |                                           +
+----------+--------+
|                   |                            +----------------+
|                   |           Feeds dog        |                |
| Man               | +----------------------->  |                |
|                   |                            |    Dog         |
|                   |                            |                |
+-------------------+                            +----------------+
```

I use [ASCII flow](http://asciiflow.com) for this but there's other ways to do it

Comment: "the preferred way to do graphs and diagrams on SE is using ASCII and code blocks": Preferred? Really?! I doubt so: do you have any statistics across the sites?

Comment: Nope. Or posting an image :p

Comment: This should be avoided, since it creates a very confusing experience for screen readers (and isn't responsive for mobile users). I wrote about [what an ASCII table sounds like](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/418553/6083675), so just imagine that but even less rhyme or reason, since there's no way to make sense of this with a screen reader. It would be preferable to use an image with appropriate alt text, which doesn't create a bunch of random chatter in the middle of the post like this does.

Comment: Wow! That's amazing tool!

Comment: Good point, this tool's "Extended ASCII" doestn't render well on mobile, bit Basic ASCII is beink rendered fine. 

But issue about scrren readers raised by @Laurel is conserning :-(